# issue regarding property of class shows null

Tags: iphone, ios

i am making game in which i am not using navigation controller but hiding and unhiding different controllers now my problem is as below

This Is going to be view long description you can understand what i am talking about

my flowConverViewController is like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FlowCoverView.h"
#import "NewGameController.h"
#import "MenuController.h"


@class NewGameController;


@interface FlowCoverViewController : UIViewController <FlowCoverViewDelegate>
{

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NewGameController *game;



- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;



@end
```

flowcontroller.m is like below

when user click on image then image get selected and game should get start
for that delegate method get called which is below

```
- (void)flowCover:(FlowCoverView *)view didSelect:(int)image
{
    NSLog(@"Selected Index %d",image);

    UIImage *newimage = [self flowCover:view cover:image];

    [



    NSLog(@"%@",[self.game menu]); // this shows null 
    NSLog(@"%@",self.game); // this shows null thats why my below methods which are in another class is not getting called 

    [self.game menu] playMenuSound];



     // game is object of newGameController that we created in .h file and in 
same way in newgamecontroller there is object properly of menu class and 
playMenuSound is method in menu class





  [self.game imagePickedFromPuzzleLibrary:newimage];
    [self.game startNewGame];


}
```

only problem is this methods are not getting called as it shows null i know that i can alloc init them but i cant do that previous data will get lost i have alloc init this properties in previous classes 
    .

```
 newgamecontroller.h

    @property (nonatomic, assign) MenuController *menu;

    newgamecontroller.m



      {
      FlowCoverViewController *c = [[FlowCoverViewController alloc] init];

        c.game = self;

        NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TestFC" owner:self options:nil];
        c = [array objectAtIndex:0];

            [self presentModalViewController:c animated:YES];
        }
```

Comment: Is there a `self.game = [[NewGameController alloc] init...]` somewhere in your code? Otherwise it will be nil.

Comment: as i said i have done this all in the beginning of game and only one object should be there in whole game cant great new one

Comment: what if i make all the class object property strong? will it work?

Comment: I know i am what else i can say in this stucky situation :[

Comment: can you show the code where you assign the NewGameController to your game property?

Comment: ok i am pesting this above so you can see clearly

Comment: posted please check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, you do:

```
FlowCoverViewController *c = [[FlowCoverViewController alloc] init];

c.game = self;
```

and then you assign to `c` a different object with:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TestFC" owner:self options:nil];
c = [array objectAtIndex:0];

[self presentModalViewController:c animated:YES];
```

How could `c` still have the property `c.game` set properly??

EDIT: Try instead

```
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TestFC" owner:self options:nil];
FlowCoverViewController *c = [array objectAtIndex:0];
[self presentViewController:c animated:YES completion:nil]
```

and let me know.

Comment: so how to over come this situation make 2 object one for that array and one for c.game?

Comment: this is what i did still showing null   FlowCoverViewController *c = [[FlowCoverViewController alloc] init];
    FlowCoverViewController *forarray ;
forarray = [array objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: You don't need to initialize your `FlowCoverViewController` with `[[FlowCoverViewController alloc] init];`, as you are already initializing it with `loadNibNamed`! then you just use this initialized view controller, it's really quite straightforward! :)